# How to not :focus on select if its not opened?

Tags: css

I want to not affect my select input with the select:focus when it's not opened so that the input will go back to the way it was before it was opened (input with 8px border-radius).

In this image, on the left is when I open the select and on the right is after opening the select.

[image]

this is my css:

```
select
{
height: 42px;
cursor: pointer;
text-align-last:center;
border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}
select:focus
{
border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect that with css. Since you are attaching css on focus, you should use jQuery to bind an event on select to focus out.

Example:

```
$('#your-select-id option').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('select').focusout():
});
```

Ofcourse that this is not the only way, and probably not the best, but you get my idea. :)